# How to lower infamy?

Tags: victoria-2

I am playing as Brazil. I have attacked several of my neighbors without justification, and brought my infamy up to 95. This resulted in the Netherlands declaring war together with their ally Great Britain, although I have managed to fight them off and get peace.

I would like to continue conquering my neighbors, but since I don't seem to be getting war justifications, I would increase my infamy and probably have the whole world attack me. How can I lower infamy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to reduce? release nations (they'll become your sphere) is the easiest and fastest way. You're not really supposed to go over 25, so at 95 I doubt there's much you can do.  It's possible, for some countries, that when they 'change tags' their infamy, relations, alliances, etc are reset to 0, for example, from Prussia to North German Empire to Germany, or Colombia to Grand Colombia. But I don't know if Brazil has that option.  Other than that it's slowly over time, and some events and decisions may lower it 1-3 points but those are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Infamy is slowly reduced gradually over time. You can release a nation as a satellite and receive a small reprieve on your infamy. Additionally, there are a few decisions that will reduce infamy by a small amount (2 or 3), but they are rare.

This is an intentional design choice by Paradox - infamy is designed to discourage you from conquering other nations and being generally warlike.